# Load testing in Postman using GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, postman, load-testing, web-api-testing

I want to perform load testing using Postman for GraphQL API. The requirement is that I need to confirm whether the application is able to withstand 200 concurrent requests. But in Postman Canary I am not able to specify 200 concurrent requests. Can any one help on this.

Comment: https://blog.postman.com/postman-api-performance-testing/ this link might be very helpful how we can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do load testing using a browser plugin, consider using a proper [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) instead.

Any load testing tool which supports HTTP protocol will fit but the most convenient is most probably [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which has special [`GraphQL HTTP Request` sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think load testing in Postman is possible for GraphQL APIS.

You can achieve that by the following steps -

1. Press `+` icon to add request.
2. Select POST method from the dropdown menu.
3. Goto Body > select graphql from the option.
4. Write query.

It should look something like this -

[image]

Write tests for your performance testing in the tests field -

```
pm.test("Response time is less than 1sec", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(1000);
});
```

Now press Runner. It is at right bottom corner.

You may now select Functional test or Load performance tests.
Configure as per your requirements.

For your case, you need to select performance and put virtual users to 200. You may also select the duration for which you want to test.
Now select the API request by drag and drop or by selecting files in your pc.

[image]

Now press run to run tests and it will give you the load tests result-

[image]

Detailed solution can be found at- https://dev.to/extinctsion/load-test-on-graphql-apis-using-postman-2lhc